# Should I use null models when I do GLM?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, generalized-linear-model, model

I'm using generalized linear models (with negative bin. most of the time) to examine relations between waterbird abundance (response variable) and some environmental variables such as water level (predictor variables). I've built models, performed model selection and validated my models. All is fine. I have working models. Now, I wanna know whether I have to build null models as well and compare them to my models. Is it necessary? I'm really new to statistics so I'm not really familiar with basic concepts like null models. I'd appreciate some simple explanation. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assessing whether your model is doing more than just overfitting your training data is of course of value (this is what you would get from a test versus a null model). Knowing whether each predictor contributes something would also be of interest (not something you would get fruition such a test).

Clearly,  you have done extensive model building and variable selection on the training data. Thus, any simple test of your model versus a null model on the training data is invalid. Such a test would need to be conducted on an independent hold out test set of data.

Alternatively, if you can codify *everything* you did,  you could try to bootstrap your whole model building process and assess your model versus a null model / assess each predictor.

Comment: Thanks for the fast replies. Björn, so what you're saying is there is no need to compare my models to null models. Did I get it right?

Comment: There is a need to evaluate the model. One evaluation is against a null model, but a chi-square test or the like on the same data on which you build the model is invalid, unless you do very complicated things (e.g. bootstrapping the data, sau, 999 times and repeating the model building on each of these data sets and doing an appropriate evaluation on that). It's much easier if you have another independent set of data.

Comment: A test against a null model is also not the only thing to look at, e.g. it would also be interesting how well a model with each predictor left out in turn would perform on an independent test set,  how well the predictions are calibrated and what the test set receiver operator curve or RMSE/bias/etc. looks like.

Answer (score -2):

This is good practice, to build a null model and compare it to your model, to check if your model is any good, or at least better then the null model. If it is not then you should throw your model away and accept the null model, since you do not have enough confidence in it's validity.

If you are doing this in r the glm function will return a null model deviance as well, which you can use to test for significance and get the p-value. Or alternatively build a null model and compare it with your model with an ANOVA.